# Localizing the sign-in button

Tags: authentication, google-plus

hallo following this tutorial

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#customizing_the_sign-in_button

when i implement the localization script to show the button in korean, german or whatever the g+ button dissapear

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Specify the language code prior to loading the JavaScript API
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'ko'
  }

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Maybe im doing something wrong but the code looks so easy...
thank you for your time and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck, Ian Barber just wrote a blog post about localizing Google+:

http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/08/google-sign-in-localisation.html

That should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the code is that you are missing a semicolon after the global window config markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Specify the language code prior to loading the JavaScript API
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'ko'
  };

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
```

Should work.